# Closed Statement after save

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring boot with Jpa Repository.  I save some records in a loop and after all records have been saved the exception below is printed.

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Instrução Fechada
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleClosedStatement.getMaxRows(OracleClosedStatement.java:3578) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.getMaxRows(OracleStatementWrapper.java:150) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.getMaxRows(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl.close(ResourceRegistryStandardImpl.java:165) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl.releaseResources(ResourceRegistryStandardImpl.java:307) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]

here is my code:

```
    @Transactional
public void resgatarPremios(List<ResgatePremio> resgates) {

    if(resgates != null && !resgates.isEmpty()) {
        Vendedor vendedor = vendedorRepository.buscarRca(resgates.get(0).getCodigoVendedor());

        for(ResgatePremio resgatePremio : resgates) {

            Premio premio = premioRepository.findById(resgatePremio.getCodigoPremio()).get();
            resgatePremio.setCodigoVendedor(vendedor.getCodigo());
            resgatePremioRepository.save(resgatePremio);

            MovimentacaoContaCorrentePontos movimentacaoContaCorrentePontos = new MovimentacaoContaCorrentePontos();
            movimentacaoContaCorrentePontos.setCodigoContaCorrentePontos(1L);
            movimentacaoContaCorrentePontos.setDataHoraMovimentacao(LocalDateTime.now());
            movimentacaoContaCorrentePontos.setCodigoVendedor(vendedor.getCodigo());
            movimentacaoContaCorrentePontos.setQuantidadePontosMovimentada(resgatePremio.getQuantidade() * premio.getQuantidadePontos() * -1);
            movimentacaoContaCorrentePontosRepository.save(movimentacaoContaCorrentePontos);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.

I changed the oracle driver version of ojdbc6 to ojdbc7